# How to move some git commits into a new repo?

Tags: git

I am using this [rest-more](https://github.com/cardinalblue/rest-more) repository, which contains many implementations of the web-api (such as Facebook or Linkedin). I forked that repository, and in my branch I added my own implementation of another web api.

However now I find that it is pretty hard to keep updated with the original repository. I rebase my branch every time the original repository changes, which is pretty tedious. So I want to split out my own implementation to a standalone repository.

All my commits are in my branch grouped together. Only one commit is touching a file from the original repository.

Is there an easy way to move my commits into a new repository? I want to do this so I can preserve my commit histories.

Comment: why not simply clone it?

Comment: I need to make a new gem, with a different namespace. And it makes sense to create a new repo than to discard 95% of the original repository content/history.

Comment: I assume all your commits are linear, no merges, right?

Comment: @mvp Yes, and I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first open a new repository:

```
git init new-repo
```

I then pushed my branch to that repository:

```
cd rest-more
git push ../new-repo/ my_branch

cd ../new-repo
git co my_branch
```

I created a new empty initial commit:

```
git checkout --orphan newroot
git commit --allow-empty -m 'root commit'
```

Then I rebase my branch to this starting point, use interactive flag to pick only my commits:

```
git rebase --onto newroot --root my_branch -i
```

Need to resolve conflicts on the way, and finally I end up with a repository with only my commits.

(There are probably improvements to be made. Feel free to suggest anything.)

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: @EdwardFalk can only accept own answer after 2 days. Plus I want to try out mvp's answer

Comment: Heh; didn't know that. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest: just stop accepting updates from the original repository. Remove the remote repository from your .git/config file.

Otherwise, from my notes:

Say you want to move **dir1** from repository **A** to repository **B**:

Make a clone of repository **A**.  To be safe, we break the link
between the clone and **A**, to make sure none of our changes
accidentally get sent back.

```
git clone git://git.foo.com/ProjectA.git NewProject
cd NewProject
git remote rm origin
```

Strip out everything except **dir1**.

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter dir1
```

This will have made dir1 the new root, which you might want to undo:

```
mkdir dir1
mv * dir1
git commit -a
```

Now merge this repository into repository **B**

```
git clone git://git.foo.com/ProjectB.git ProjectB
cd ProjectB
git remote add repo-A-branch ~/NewProject
git pull repo-A-branch master
git remote rm repo-A-branch
```

Comment: Thanks this would definitely work in some situation. However the files I created doesn't live under one folder only. So this does not work for me. But I just found a solution, posting it now.

Answer (score 1):

I would **recommend keeping a single repository**, and **creating a second branch for your changes**.  You can then **[cherry pick](https://ariejan.net/2010/06/10/cherry-picking-specific-commits-from-another-branch/) your commits** to this new branch, to isolate your changes, and merge/rebase upstream changes and your changes into a third branch as appropriate to create releases of your code.  Keeping it in one repository makes it far easier to stay in sync with the upstream development, and having your changes on their own branch allows you to keep them isolated.  The third branch can serve as a "your changes applied to the upstream code" branch.

Comment: I want to make my commits a Ruby gem, so the dependency issue can be handled by it. Therefore making a new repository makes sense in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have strictly linear history of your commits (no merges), you can simply export all your commits as follows:

```
git format-patch <start>..<stop>
```

Where `start` and `stop` is range of commits you need (`start` is commit you started from, and `stop` is probably current `HEAD`).

This will create lots of files named `NNNNN-commit-description.patch`, NNNNN is number starting from 00001.

Then, create new empty repository and import these patches:

```
git init newrepo
cd newrepo
find <oldrepo>/*.patch | xargs git am
```

Also, instead of starting off empty repo, you may want to make first commit with some original files that you depend upon, such that all your patches can apply cleanly.

Comment: I think your solution is the cleanest. However for me some existing files were touched, so using my rebase -i is much easier than this.

Comment: that's why I suggested to make first commit with files you have changed from the base