# How can I split a single file from a git repo into a new repo?

Tags: git

I have a git repo with several directories, and a single file, `MyFile.ext`.

```
/
  LargeDir1/
  LargeDir2/
  LargeDir3/
      .
      .
      .
  MyFile.ext
```

I'd like to start a new repo with just `MyFile.ext` in it, and keep all the history pertaining to it, but ignore everything else (all the `LargeDir`s). How can I do this?

For directories, I've successfully used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864475/817630), but I tried that on a single file, and it doesn't work.

I've also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3910697/817630), which does delete everything except my file, but it also seems to leave all the history around.

Comment: see if you can 'git mv' the file into a sub directory, then use 'git subtree'.

Comment: @Gregg I will try it, but I'm pretty sure it won't work because when you move a file, you lose the git history. I've had issues with that before when using `git subtree split` on a renamed directory.

Comment: @Gregg Yeah just tried it. The only commit that comes into the new repo is the commit where the file was moved to the new directory.

Comment: I have this exact same problem and have tried both `git subtree split ...` and `git filter-branch ...` solutions without success.  Those basically only work for subdirectories where everything in it was never altered outside that directory. What I want is a commit & log history that is what you see when you run `git log MyFile.ext`.

Comment: @hepcat72 Yeah, I don't know if it's possible. I eventually gave up and lost the history.

Comment: Actually, I just figured out a (rather labrious but working) solution.  I was just compiling a set of steps for the solution, but it's based on the accepted solution to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930919/move-some-git-commits-into-a-new-repo

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `git fast-export`.

First you export the history of the file to a *fast-import stream*. Make sure you do this on the `master` branch.

```
cd oldrepo
git fast-export HEAD -- MyFile.ext >../myfile.fi
```

Then you create a new repo and import.

```
cd ..
mkdir newrepo
cd newrepo
git init
git fast-import <../myfile.fi
git checkout
```

Comment: I just tried this, but the file doesn't appear in the new repo.

Comment: @KrisHarper `fast-import` creates the commits, but not a working copy. See updated answer.

Comment: I get "fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born".

Comment: What version of `git` are you using? This works fine  with git 2.11. One some older versions of git, you might have to create an initial commit first to create the `master` branch.

Comment: Git version 2.7.4

Comment: What branch were you on when you ran `fast-export`? In my tests I was on `master`, and I can confirm this works.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I was on a branch other than master.

Comment: Excellent. Much simpler than what I figured out, and cleaner. Wish you'd answered this 2 days ago before I spent time trying to roll my own solution.

Comment: @hepcat72 It was actually your answer that made me see this question. :-) When I originally [ran into this problem](http://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/howto/making-a-subset-of-a-git-repository.html) in 2015, the first thing that I've tried was [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/esr/reposurgeon/). That pointed me to *fast-import streams*, and that lead me to `git fast-export` I'm not sure where I found this exact usage; it's not in the manual page. The point here is that it's not blindingly obvious that this is a good way to do such things.

Comment: For future reference: one can add multiple filenames or even directory names instead of `MyFile.ext`, very useful for splitting a repo in several pieces.

Comment: @KrisHarper You have to `git checkout <the-branch-name-you-were-on-in-oldrepo>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and I finally figured it out.  I had an old old directory of scripts - so old, they had originally been under RCS control.  Years ago, I made it into a git repo (without really knowing what I was doing) and I converted the RCS log and update the git log.  But I picked up development of one of the scripts and decided it needed its own repo.  The various solutions out there (subtree and filter-branch) depend on the part you're splitting out to be a directory.  You can put the file in a directory and split it out that way, but you don't get the revision history with it.  So here's how I figured out how to extract the revision history of a single file and create a new repo with it:

1. Create a branch new repo [I did it at the same level as the source-repo]

   ```
   git init <new-repo>
   ```
2. Now go into your source repo and create a file that we're going to use later to cherry-pick the file's commits:

   ```
   cd <source-repo>
   git log --reverse <target-file.ext> | \
       grep ^commit | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -c 1-7 | \
       perl -ne 'print("pick $_")' > ../commits-to-keep.txt
   ```
3. Create a temporary branch and push it to your new repo (then delete it)

   ```
   git checkout -b tmpbranch
   git push ../new-repo tmpbranch
   git checkout master
   git branch -d tmpbranch
   ```
4. Now go to your new repo and create an empty commit off of which we will rebase:

   ```
    cd ../<new-repo>
    git commit --allow-empty -m 'root commit'
    git rebase --onto master --root tmpbranch -i
   ```
5. [The only manual step] In the editor that comes up from the last command above, remove all the contents and paste in the contents of the file you created earlier: ../commits-to-keep.txt
6. Now you can switch back to the master branch, merge, and then clean up the temporary branch:

   ```
    git checkout master
    git merge tmpbranch
    git branch -d  tmpbranch
   ```

The only drawback here is that you end up with the extra empty root commit.  I found that there are ways to remove it, but for my purposes, this was good enough.

Comment: Even though @RolandSmith's answer is the way to go, I thought I'd add that my manual step can be changed to be automatic by inserting this above the rebase command: `setenv GIT_EDITOR 'vim +"%d | r ../commits-to-keep.txt | wq"'`.  This would make it possible to skip step 5.  Though you might not want to lose what already might be in `GIT_EDITOR`.  In lieu of @RolandSmith's answer, I thought about taking my answer down, but I figured I'd leave it up just to show another way to sort of do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clone the repo.
2. Filter out everything but that one file.

Cloning can be done normally with `git clone`. That will work fine on a directory like `git clone /path/to/the/repo`. Then remove remote pointing back to the clone.

```
git clone /path/to/the/repo
git remote rm origin
```

Then use [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to filter out everything but that one file. This is easiest to accomplish with an index filter that deletes all files and then restores just the one.

```
git rm --cached -qr -- . && git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT -- YOURFILENAME
```

An index filter works by checking out each individual commit with all the changes staged. You're running this command, and then recommitting it. It first removes all the changes from staging, then restores that one file to its state in that commit. `$GIT_COMMIT` is the commit being rewritten. `YOURFILENAME` is the file you want to keep.

If you're doing all branches and tags with `--all`, add a tag filter which ensures the tags are rewritten. That's as simple as `--tag-name-filter cat`. It will not change the content of the tags, but it will ensure they're moved to the rewritten commits.

Finally, you'll want `--prune-empty` to remove any now empty commits that didn't involve that file. There will be a lot of them.

Here it is all together.

```
git filter-branch \
    --index-filter 'git rm --cached -qr -- . && git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT -- YOURFILENAME' \
    --tag-name-filter cat
    --prune-empty \
    -- --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Git now recommends using [git filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) instead (you get a message about it when using filter-branch). [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58983975/79125) on one of the questions you linked has a long explanation, but here's a short example.

To remove everything except src/README.md and move it to the root:

```
pip install git-filter-repo
# Must use a fresh clone to avoid losing local history.
git clone --no-local project extracted
cd extracted/
git filter-repo --path src/README.md
git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter src/
```

We use `--path` selects the single file and `--subdirectory-filter` moves the contents of that directory to root. I can't find a way to do this in a single pass, but the second pass is much faster since the first eliminates most of the history.